# Sublime ignores eslint settings

Tags: global-variables, sublimetext3, eslint

I am using the [standard](http://standardjs.com/) linter via the [SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint)  and it seems to ignore these entries in both `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` and `~/.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "globals": {
      "describe": true,
      "it": true,
      "expect": true,
      "angular": true
  }
}
```

I am still getting these globals as undefined.
Any other way to declare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `SublimeLInter.sublime-settings`, but `~/.eslintc` file will only be used if no other eslint config files are found. Since you are using standard, I assume that you have another `.eslintrc` file somewhere. You will have to add those globals there.

Comment: Thank you, that must be the reason. I've found their settings in `package.json` - totally unexpected place!